# Simple 2-level hierarchy subclassing QAbstractItemModel

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

Having a data stored in `QVector<QVector<QString>> data;` (or alternatively a list of lists of strings if you are a Pythonist) how should I subclass `QAbstractItemModel` to be able to display (read-only) such a simple structure in `QTreeView`? I would like to see something like this:

- "group 1"

  - data[0][0]
  - data[0][1]
- "group 2"

  - data[1][0]
  - data[1][1]

etc.

From the docs, I read that I should override `index()`, `parent()`, `rowCount()`, `columnCount()` and `data()`. What is the simplest possible implementation of these methods to achieve my goal?

To make the possible answer more enlightening, how can one subclass `QAbstractItemModel` without using the internal pointers (stored in `QModelIndex`es). All the examples I have seen use the underlying model in a form of a tree with nodes (having pointers to their children and parent nodes) which make is easy to wrap inside `QAbstractItemModel` using the internal pointers. But can we use `QAbstractItemModel` even without a tree/node-like underlying structure and without `QModelIndex`'s internal pointers? My question is based on the docs saying that you **can** use internal pointers, but I have not yet seen any example without it.

Comment: Your data structure isn't sufficient to represent a 2-level hierarchy. To be specific, there is no storage for the top-level strings - i.e. "group 1, "group 2", etc. In python terms, you'd need something like: `[["group1", [1, 2, 3]], ["group 2", [1, 2, 3]], ...]`.

Comment: If you did not use internal pointers, how would you map a model-index to a location in your data structure? It looks like you would need to do a bottom-up traversal using `parent()` to calculate a chain of indexes into the data structure. And this would have to be continually re-calculated  by almost every method of the model, making it a (cumulatively) very expensive operation. So maybe that's why all the examples are based on internal pointers (which effectively cache the expensive look-up operation).

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt really matter which level of hierarchy you use, Create custom class node
with QVector(commonly QList<QString> QList is similar to std::deque) to store data, and pointer to its child nodes QList<Node*> children. Top level of hierarchy is invisible root node. Then process data in model.

Really great guide, with node and model examples:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html

You can basically copy-paste code and implement own setupModelData method.